# Why is the best and worst case of linear search of an unsorted array O(n)?

Tags: arrays, search

There's some doubt with the best case and the worst case of unsorted array.

Assume there is no duplicate element in the unsorted array.

Based on the lecturer in my university,

The best case of the unsorted array is O(n) while the worst case is also O(n). I do understand why the worst case of the unsorted array is O(n) because the algorithm have to search for all the elements if the element is in the last index of the array. However, how is the best case of the unsorted array O(n)?

Assume the user input a number that can be found in the first index of the unsorted array, why is the best case still considered as the O(n)?

Once the element is found, it returns true, and break out of the algorithm, hence the best case should be O(1).

Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546291/searching-an-unsorted-array), it says that the algorithm will continue to search despite finding the element therefore, the best case is O(n).

The various answer is the link given does not exactly explain why is it O(n).

Comment: Best case of *what operation*?

Comment: i've updated the question. I meant the best and worse cast of searching an unsorted array.

Comment: What kind of searching algorithm we are talking about? There are different approaches for different problems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Search_algorithms or http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-algorithms/

Comment: @Teomanshipahi isn't the only way of searching an unsorted array via linear search apart from using  Grover's algorithm? nonetheless, i've updated the question above.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan if you know what algorithm you are referring, just google it and see what's it's best/worst case and why. Also something looks missing here, in your case, looks like search list would have duplicate elements, and you will need to go all the way end to find it. so it is O(n).

Comment: @Teomanshipahi i've edited the question to clarify your doubt if there's a duplication of element in the unsorted array.

Comment: Then you misunderstood your lecturer, best case of linear search for single item is Θ(1). http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-2-asymptotic-analysis/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPyuH4qXLZ0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is actually covered at another StackExchange [site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194433/is-this-a-proper-rule-for-identifying-the-big-o-notation-of-an-algorithm). The question and answer at that link will explain how Big-O notation is calculated.

To summarize that site, Big-O calculates an *algorithm's* [worst case](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) complexity. Yes, there will be edge cases for any given specific execution of that algorithm which are O(1), but on average, the algorithm for searching an unordered array is to iterate over each element in turn, until it is found.

Generally, this is implemented using a `for` loop type construct:

```
for element in list:
    if element == thing_to_match:
        return True
return False
```

That algorithm runs in O(n) time, since the construct of a `for` loop means, in the worst case, you have to look at every possible element.

Comment: in the link that you gave, it consist of an algorithm which allows one to define what is the best and worst case. what i mean is generically why is big-oh of an unsorted array O(n).

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan, which is what I explained. Big-O measures an _algorithm's_ complexity, not a particular running of the algorithm. The _algorithm_ for searching an unsorted array is the same, regardless of whether a given execution of the algorithm is its best case (element is in position 1) or its worst case (element is in position n). The Big-Oh notation of that _algorithm_ is O(n). Big-Oh measures the _algorithm_ without taking into consideration any particular input to that algorithm.

Comment: in that case, why is the best case of linear search of the sorted array O(1) then?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan, because the best case is that the element is in the first position, so you look at 1 element. But that's confusing the issue. You shouldn't talk about "best case" in terms of Big-Oh. Big-Oh is a measurement of the worst case runtime of an algorithm. Teoman Shipahi commented correctly, the actual Big-Oh is dependent on the algorithm. With sorted inputs, you can use different algorithms that don't require a linear search of the input, so they have different Big-Oh notations.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan, also to clarify on the last comment by Teoman Shipahi, he specifically said "best case of linear search for **single item**" is O(1). This is true, since the algorithm for searching a list which only ever contains a single item is a conditional statement, that always executes just once.